# Deterministic non-harmonic motion of a single spring

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, oscillators, dissipation

Is there anything describing a spring's motion when e.g pulled and released, or pushed and released, with no mass-body attached to the spring. I.e not your usual "mass motion on a spring"-equation.

I'm looking for a description of a spring in motion that doesn't deal with any external inertia or force. Intuitively the motion is non-harmonic and the spring just quickly contract or extract back to ground state and briefly vibrate frenetically. Does is exist a deterministic description of this motion?

Comment: Do you mean a [damped harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Damped_harmonic_oscillator)?

Comment: @Qmechanic That's more or less my question. Can this be viewed as a damped harmonic oscillation, as in when dealing with predictive counter forces (e.g friction).

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: Then the tricky part is to compute `m` since there's no external body, `m` is the mass of the spring itself, but distributed along the spring, and `k` is not constant everywhere along the spring

Comment: Check out http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7773/ if you are into Mathematica notebooks.  The problem basically the same as longitudinal vibrations of a rigid rod where the only mass in the system is the rod itself.